# how to create an index for the content of a page including web parts with kentico?

Tags: search, indexing, web-parts, kentico

I'm creating an index for pages but when I use it with the smart search is just working for the title of the page, not for the content of it.
I would like to search including the content of the web parts inside of all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default page index will index content of text web parts placed on pages (Editable text, Static text and similar), but it will not include content of other pages or objects displayed through web parts (eg. something displayed via a repeater).

For this situation you can use page crawler index instead which will make HTTP request to each page, download and process HTML output to an index and in this way it will index everything that is rendered in the page:

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/setting-up-search-on-your-website/using-locally-stored-search-indexes/creating-local-search-indexes/defining-local-page-indexes